# Get latitude and longitude from cellid, lac, MCC, MNC in c# for console or wpf applicaiton

Tags: c#, wpf, api, console-application

I am creating a system that gets the cellid, MCC, MNC and LAC and I want to use opencellid to get the latitude and longitude from these information, I didn't find resources in the internet, so I don't know where to start. if you can help me to find out how to do that, or give me an alternative solution to find latitude and longitude from these informations it would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check below code i hope this helpful  :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class GoogleMapsApi
    {
        static byte[] PostData(int MCC, int MNC, int LAC, int CID)
        {

        /* The shortCID parameter follows heuristic experiences:

         * Sometimes UMTS CIDs are build up from the original GSM CID (lower 4 hex digits)

         * and the RNC-ID left shifted into the upper 4 digits.

         */

        byte[] pd = new byte[] {

    0x00, 0x0e,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x1b,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x11

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x15

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x19

    0x00, 0x00,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x1f

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x23

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x27

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Offset 0x2b

    0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,

    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

};
        Console.WriteLine(pd.Length);

        bool isUMTSCell = ((Int64)CID > 65535);

        /*    if (shortCID)

                CID &= 0xFFFF;      /* Attempt to resolve the cell using the

                            GSM CID part */

        if ((Int64)CID > 65536) /* GSM: 4 hex digits, UTMS: 6 hex

                        digits */

            pd[0x1c] = 5;

        else

            pd[0x1c] = 3;

        pd[0x11] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x12] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x13] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x14] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x15] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x16] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x17] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x18] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x27] = (byte)((MNC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x28] = (byte)((MNC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x29] = (byte)((MNC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2a] = (byte)((MNC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2b] = (byte)((MCC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2c] = (byte)((MCC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2d] = (byte)((MCC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x2e] = (byte)((MCC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x1f] = (byte)((CID >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x20] = (byte)((CID >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x21] = (byte)((CID >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x22] = (byte)((CID >> 0) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x23] = (byte)((LAC >> 24) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x24] = (byte)((LAC >> 16) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x25] = (byte)((LAC >> 8) & 0xFF);

        pd[0x26] = (byte)((LAC >> 0) & 0xFF);

        return pd;

    }

    static public string[] GetLatLng(int MCC, int MNC, int LAC, int CID)
    {

        string[] result = new string[2];

        try
        {

            String url = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(

                new Uri(url));

            req.Method = "POST";

            byte[] pd = PostData(MCC, MNC, LAC, CID);

            req.ContentLength = pd.Length;

            req.ContentType = "application/binary";

            Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream();

            outputStream.Write(pd, 0, pd.Length);

            outputStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            byte[] ps = new byte[res.ContentLength];

            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            while (totalBytesRead < ps.Length)
            {

                totalBytesRead += res.GetResponseStream().Read(

                    ps, totalBytesRead, ps.Length - totalBytesRead);

            }

            //for(int i=0;i<ps.Length;i++)
            //    Console.WriteLine(ps[i]);
            string r = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ps);
            Console.WriteLine(r);



            if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {

                short opcode1 = (short)(ps[0] << 8 | ps[1]);

                byte opcode2 = ps[2];

                int ret_code = (int)((ps[3] << 24) | (ps[4] << 16) |

                               (ps[5] << 8) | (ps[6]));

                if (ret_code == 0)
                {

                    double lat = ((double)((ps[7] << 24) | (ps[8] << 16)

                                 | (ps[9] << 8) | (ps[10]))) / 1000000;

                    double lon = ((double)((ps[11] << 24) | (ps[12] <<

                                 16) | (ps[13] << 8) | (ps[14]))) /

                                 1000000;

                    result[0] = lat.ToString();
                    result[1] = lon.ToString();
                    return result;

                }

                else
                {

                    return result;
                }

            }

            else

                return result;

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result[0] = ex.Message;
            return result;

        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the API information here:
http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/API

Comment: It's best to avoid link only answers. Try to include some of the relevant information from the link if you can.